# Using iText, how to give Path to store PDF file from Device or Emulator?

Tags: android, itext

I am developing Invoice App, so i am using iText to create PDF file, like invoice. I want to store PDF file in sd card OR in the Computer itself. But it is not working because, Path is not get accesseble by the App.

But when i tried the same code in Java Application , then file is created sucessfully.Path is given in the computer LocalDisk.

I want to give the Path of file to be stored,

1. In the SD Card of real Device.
2. In the Computer LocalDisk (in case App works on Emulater).

How to do ? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the SD Card of real Device.

If by "the SD Card", you mean what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), you have a number of options for getting a path to a spot to write your file. Off the cuff, I would recommend [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` on the `Environment` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)).

If by "the SD Card", you mean [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), that is not supported by the Android SDK before Android 4.4.

> In the Computer LocalDisk (in case App works on Emulater).

That is not supported. The emulator has no ability to write into the filesystem of the development PC. The emalator can have its own emulated external storage, though.

Comment: Thanks @ Now i have saved PDF file into external storage. But how to view PDF file or Print ?

Comment: @SandeepGupta: Start an activity with an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, the way you would any PDF file. Android 4.4 has some built-in printing APIs that can handle PDF.

Comment: should i have to create an Activity to make view of that pdf then can proceed for Print.

Comment: @SandeepGupta: No, that should not be necessary. You will need to create a `PrintDocumentAdapter` that can use your PDF file. I have a simplified one of these in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Printing/PrintManager). If you have additional concerns regarding printing, please ask a new Stack Overflow question.